# noSuchMethodError setDefaultTransactionManager - HIBERNATE CACHING

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, maven, caching

I'm trying to make an application with hibernate caching for several hours but I'm getting the error:
noSuchMethodError setDefaultTransactionManager

Its my first Hibernate application and I will be really grateful for your help.

my maven dependencies for cache:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.sf.ehcache</groupId>
    <artifactId>ehcache-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-ehcache</artifactId>
    <version>3.3.2.GA</version>
</dependency>
```

hibernate.cfg.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration SYSTEM 
"http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect">
            org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
        </property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">
            com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
        </property>

        <!-- Assume test is the database name -->
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url">
            jdbc:mysql://localhost:3036/test?autoReconnect=true&amp;useUnicode=true&amp;characterEncoding=UTF-8
        </property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username">
            root
        </property>


        <property name="current_session_context_class">org.hibernate.context.ManagedSessionContext</property>
        <property name="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache">true</property>
        <property name="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache">true</property>
        <property name="hibernate.cache.region.factory_class">net.sf.ehcache.hibernate.EhCacheRegionFactory</property>

        <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>
        <property name="hibernate.bytecode.use_reflection_optimizer">false</property>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
        <property name="show_sql">true</property>
        <mapping class="info.talacha.filmweb.models.Movie" />
        <mapping class="info.talacha.filmweb.models.Person" />
        <mapping class="movies.Cinema" />
        <mapping class="movies.Timetable" />
        <mapping class="movies.PopularMovie" />
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Every class which I want to be cached is with Cache annotation:

```
@Entity
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_WRITE)
@Table(name = "people")
public class Person implements Serializable{
}
```

ehcache.xml

```
<ehcache xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://ehcache.org/ehcache.xsd"
    maxBytesLocalHeap ="900">

<defaultCache 
    eternal="false" 
    timeToIdleSeconds="300" 
    timeToLiveSeconds="1200" 
    overflowToDisk="false"> 
    </defaultCache>
</ehcache>
```

Answer (score 0):

In classpath present several ehcache libs, look
https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=1008979

First dependency "ehcache-core" is not required, remove it.
In second dependency "hibernate-ehcache" correct version of "ehcache" already present, look on http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-ehcache/3.3.2.GA